# Angle Iron Cleat at Slab-Slab connection

Tags: structural-engineering

We regularly bolt an angle iron against an existing building element (flange down), and use the flange as support for a new concrete slab. Is there any design approach to assist with the sizing / spacing of the chemical anchors as well as confirming the suitability of the angled section?  Epoxy anchors are one form of chemical anchor we use. There are other types of (chemical) bonding agents available like polyesters, vinyl esters as well as hybrid systems.

We have tried various design software packages none of them is very helpful with this configuration. Therefore a manual approach is all that is left, it seems.

Comment: I'm assuming a vertical-horizontal configuration (stair step vs riser). Are you suspending the horizontal member from the angle iron or is the angle iron supporting the load of the horizontal member?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...and use the flange as support for a new concrete slab

By this, I assume you mean a shelf angle (or a connection angle) to support a concrete floor.  The image below is an example from the *PCI Design Handbook*, 7th Edition.

[image: Shelf Angle]

Section 6.6.5 of the *PCI Design Handbook*, 7th Edition goes through a design example of an unstiffened connection angle.  You will likely find similar design examples in previous editions of that *Handbook*, thought not necessarily with the same section number.

[This article](http://www.structuremag.org/wp-content/uploads/C-StrucDesign-Mcginley-May131.pdf) from [STRUCTURE Magazine](http://www.structuremag.org/?p=219) also goes through some design methodology for shelf angles.